# How do I generate an IAM policy for making snapshots?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have volumes mounted on EC2 instances of which I would like to make snapshots.

I created a new IAM user with the following policy:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "...",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
        "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
        "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
        "ec2:DescribeTags",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:MY_USER_ID"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added the access key and secret to my `~/.bashrc` and sourced it. When I run `ec2-describe-snapshots` I get this response: `Client.UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

When my `"Resource"` was just `"*"` I was able to list all types of Amazon's snapshots. I am looking to create snapshots owned by/visible to just me in the `eu-west-1` region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As wisely posted at [How can I limit EC2 describe images permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832819/how-can-i-limit-ec2-describe-images-permissions), resource level permissions are not implemented at all on `ec2:Describe*` actions.

In Reality you need to limit access based on other things and not the resource ARN.

Comment: I see! Well I tried directly just creating a snapshot with the same policy but I still encountered an error. I changed my `Resource` to `*` again and I was able to create the snapshot. Can I assume that the snapshots will always be created as private to my account?

Comment: By default yes. The snapshots are private unless set to public